# How to display json response array on html page

Tags: javascript, json

I want to print json array data into html page ,I have json response like this

```
[
    {
        "doctor_id": "1",
        "doctor_type": "doctor",
        "reg_number": "1",
        "name": "abc",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com"
     }
     {
        "doctor_id": "2",
        "doctor_type": "doctor",
        "reg_number": "2",
        "name": "xyz",
        "email_id": "xyz@gmail.com"
     }
]
```

i collected this response in javascript variable `var data` .
i have table where i want display data

```
<table border="1">
 <tr> 
    <td>Doctor ID:</td> <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>Type:</td> <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>Registration number</td> <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>Name</td> <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>Email</td> <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My script code is

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data); 
for (var i=0;i<parsedJSON.length;i++) 
{ alert(parsedJSON[i].doctor_type); }
```

I just tried to alert data in page like above

Comment: Did you  write any `HTML` code?

Comment: yes, i have table in my html page

Comment: You can post your HTML and update question

Comment: Did you try any code?

Comment: yes , but it not working, i used         var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);
       for (var i=0;i<parsedJSON.length;i++) {
            alert(parsedJSON[i].doctor_type);
         }

Comment: Okay! Then  wait

Comment: then i tried   $each  $.each(data, function(){
          $("ul").append("doctor_type: "+this['doctor_type']+" reg_number: "+this['reg_number']+"");
          alert(this['doctor_type']);
    });

Comment: @Tejaswee Code does no help in a comment. [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help

```js
var data = [
    {
        "doctor_id": "1",
        "doctor_type": "doctor",
        "reg_number": "1",
        "name": "abc",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com"
     },
     {
        "doctor_id": "2",
        "doctor_type": "doctor",
        "reg_number": "2",
        "name": "xyz",
        "email_id": "xyz@gmail.com"
     }
];

var dataTable = document.querySelector("#dataTable");

data.forEach((item, i) => {
    var row = dataTable.insertRow();
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = item.doctor_id;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = item.doctor_type;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = item.reg_number;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = item.name;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = item.email_id;
  });
```

```css
#dataTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="dataTable" border="1">
  <thead id="tableHead">
    <tr id="tableRow">
      <th>Doctor ID</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Registration Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: @Tejaswee please check console and provide more details

Comment: TypeError: dataTable is null

Comment: @Tejaswee did you add table in html that i have added ?

Comment: @Tejaswee please create codesandbox and provide link will check, thanks